# Why does my C++ program sometimes crash upon leaving a method

Tags: c++, matrix, gdb, g++

I'm trying to write a little library that implements matrices and a few basic operations on them. Right now I'm trying to implement an LU decomposition. The problem is that my program sometimes runs without problems and other times it terminates early and windows just says "test.exe has topped working".

I'm compiling using g++ with the following options:

```
g++  "./Lineair Algebra/Matrix.cpp" "./Lineair Algebra/Determinant.cpp" test.cpp -g -lm -std=c++11 -o test.exe
```

The file Determinant.cpp is included because I intend to use the decomposition for calculating determinants with a size > 3.

The code which calls the decomposition is in test.cpp:
test.cpp:

```
#include "./Lineair Algebra/Matrix.hpp"
#include "./Lineair Algebra/Determinant.hpp"

int main (void)
{
    Matrix n (4,4);
    Matrix& nRef = n;

    n.set(0,0,2);
    n.set(0,3,1);
    n.set(2,0,-2);
    n.set(3,0,4);
    n.set(1,1,1);
    n.set(2,1,-3);
    n.set(3,1,-4);
    n.set(1,2,3);
    n.set(2,2,-5);
    n.set(3,2,4);
    n.set(0,3,1);
    n.set(1,3,-3);
    n.set(2,3,2);
    n.set(3,3,6);

    Matrix tmp1 (4,4);
    Matrix tmp2 (4,4);
    Matrix& tmp1Ref = tmp1;
    Matrix& tmp2Ref = tmp2;

    n.print();

    cout << "Decomposing" << endl;

    n.LUDecompose(tmp1Ref,tmp2Ref);

    cout << "Test.cpp regained control" << endl;

    n.print();

    tmp1.print();

    tmp2.print();

    cout << "Done printing, returning 0 from test.cpp" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Matrix.hpp:

```
#ifndef MATRIX_HPP
#define MATRIX_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using  namespace std;

typedef vector< vector<double> > Table;

class Matrix
{
    private:
        Table array;
        int rows;
        int cols;

    public:
        Matrix();

        Matrix(int r, int c);

        Matrix(Table t);

        ~Matrix(void);

        //Matrix (double** dp, size_t r, size_t c);

        Matrix operator+ (Matrix m);

        Matrix operator+ (double d);

        Matrix operator- (Matrix m);

        Matrix operator- (double d);

        Matrix operator* (Matrix m);

        Matrix operator* (double d);

        void operator*= (double d);

        Matrix operator/ (double d);

        void operator/= (double d);

        bool operator== (Matrix m);

        bool operator!= (Matrix m);

        bool isSquare () const;

        bool isRow () const;

        bool isCol () const;

        int getElements () const;

        int getRows() const;

        int getCols() const;

        int getSize () const;

        double get(int row, int col) const;

        void getSubMatrix (int rowFrom, int colFrom, int rowTo, int colTo, Matrix& dest) const;

        void getTable (Table& t) const;

        int getRow (int row, Matrix& dest) const;

        int getCol (int col, Matrix& dest) const;

        void set(int row, int col, double value);

        void set (Table& t);

        void expand (int r, int c);

        int addRows (int row, const Matrix& rrm);

        int addCols (int col, const Matrix& rcm);

        void gaussEliminate (Matrix& lower, Matrix& upper);

        int LUDecompose (Matrix& l, Matrix& u);

        int transpose (Matrix& dest);

        void print ();
};

#endif
```

Matrix.cpp is about 600 lines long so I'll try to post only the necessary:

Matrix.cpp: constructors and destructor (only used for debugging)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "Matrix.hpp"

using  namespace std;

typedef vector< vector<double> > Table;

Matrix::Matrix()
{
    array = Table (1, vector <double> (1));
    array[0][0] = 0;
}

Matrix::Matrix(int r, int c)
{
    array = Table (c, vector <double> (r));

    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            this->set(i, j, 0);
        }
    }
}

Matrix::Matrix(Table t) : array(t) {}

Matrix::~Matrix(void)
{
    cout << "Deleting matrix" << endl;
}
```

Matrix.cpp: LUDecompose method

```
int Matrix::LUDecompose (Matrix& refLower, Matrix& refUpper)
{
    if (!this->isSquare())
    {
        cout << "Given matrix is not a square matrix" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        double c = 0;

        Matrix rowMatrix (1,this->getCols());
        Matrix& refRowMatrix = rowMatrix;

        refUpper = *this;

        for (int i = 1; i < this->getRows(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (i >= j)
                {
                    refUpper.getRow(j,refRowMatrix);

                    rowMatrix *= refUpper.get(i,j);
                    rowMatrix /= refUpper.get(j,j);
                    rowMatrix *= -1.0;

                    c = refUpper.get(i,j) / refUpper.get(j,j);

                    refUpper.addRows(i,refRowMatrix);

                    refLower.set(i, j, c);

                    cout << "Leaving if statement" << endl;
                }
                cout << "Leaving inner for loop" << endl;
            }
            cout << "Leaving outer for loop" << endl;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < this->getRows(); i++)
        {
            refLower.set(i,i,1);
        }

        cout << "Returning 0 from LUDecompose" << endl;

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now I know there's libs out there that do this for me but that's not really the point, I'm just trying to learn here.
Also keep in mind that I'm mainly self-taught so my code probably doesn't conform to (some people's) professional standards.

When I run this code outside of gdb this is the output I get:

```
Deleting matrix
Deleting matrix

[2      0       0       1       ]
[0      1       3       -3      ]
[-2     -3      -5      2       ]
[4      -4      4       6       ]

Decomposing
Deleting matrix
Leaving if statement
Leaving inner for loop
Leaving outer for loop
Leaving if statement
Leaving inner for loop
Leaving if statement
Leaving inner for loop
Leaving outer for loop
Leaving if statement
Leaving inner for loop
Leaving if statement
Leaving inner for loop
Leaving if statement
Leaving inner for loop
Leaving outer for loop
Returning 0 from LUDecompose
Deleting matrix
Test.cpp regained control

[2      0       0       1       ]
[0      1       3       -3      ]
[-2     -3      -5      2       ]
[4      -4      4       6       ]


[1      0       0       0       ]
[0      1       0       0       ]
[-1     -3      1       0       ]
[2      -4      4       1       ]


[2      0       0       1       ]
[0      1       3       -3      ]
[0      0       4       -6      ]
[0      0       0       16      ]

Done printing, returning 0 from test.cpp
Deleting matrix
Deleting matrix
Deleting matrix
```

for a succesful run, or the following for an unsuccesful run:

```
Deleting matrix
Deleting matrix

[2      0       0       1       ]
[0      1       3       -3      ]
[-2     -3      -5      2       ]
[4      -4      4       6       ]

Decomposing
Deleting matrix
Leaving if statement
Leaving inner for loop
Leaving outer for loop
Leaving if statement
Leaving inner for loop
Leaving if statement
Leaving inner for loop
Leaving outer for loop
Leaving if statement
Leaving inner for loop
Leaving if statement
Leaving inner for loop
Leaving if statement
Leaving inner for loop
Leaving outer for loop
Returning 0 from LUDecompose
Deleting matrix
```

When running the code from GDB it always crashes and GDB produces the following output:

```
[New Thread 1584.0x8b8]
[New Thread 1584.0xdb8]
[New Thread 1584.0x13fc]
[New Thread 1584.0x10b8]
Deleting matrix
Deleting matrix

[2      0       0       1       ]
[0      1       3       -3      ]
[-2     -3      -5      2       ]
[4      -4      4       6       ]

Decomposing
Deleting matrix
Leaving if statement
Leaving inner for loop
Leaving outer for loop
Leaving if statement
Leaving inner for loop
Leaving if statement
Leaving inner for loop
Leaving outer for loop
Leaving if statement
Leaving inner for loop
Leaving if statement
Leaving inner for loop
Leaving if statement
Leaving inner for loop
Leaving outer for loop
Returning 0 from LUDecompose
Deleting matrix
warning: HEAP[test.exe]:
warning: Heap block at 00801188 modified at 00801198 past requested size of 8


Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x76fdee8b in ?? ()
```

I've looked up the error online and I suspect it's about something going out of scope but I'm failing to see why.

Please be gentle, this is my first ever SO question ;)

EDIT: Cleaned up test.cpp a bit, removed unused determinant and matrix

EDIT 2: I understand I need to debug this program. The problem is I don't understand why it's crashing. When i use bt in gdb it points me to de destructor and any frames above that all have to do with vector (de) allocators.

EDIT 3: Removed =operator, changed use of [] in constructor to at() method. And as requested, here is the set method:

```
void Matrix::set(int row, int col, double value)
{
    array[row][col] = value;
}

void Matrix::set (Table& t)
{
    if (t.size() > this->getCols())
    {
        this->expand(0,t.size() - this->getCols());
    }

    if (t[0].size() > this->getRows())
    {
        this->expand(t[0].size() - this->getRows(),0);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < t[0].size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < t.size(); j++)
        {
            this->set(i,j,t[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 4: Updated constructor to reflect Paul McKenzie's comment

EDIT 5: I'm sorry for not posting the following functions in the first place, I just figured my post was long enough already...
Anyway here you go:

```
void Matrix::operator*= (double d)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->getRows(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < this->getCols(); j++)
        {
            this->set(i, j, this->get(i,j) * d);
        }
    }
}

void Matrix::operator/= (double d)
{
    if (d != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->getRows(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < this->getCols(); j++)
            {
                this->set(i, j, this->get(i,j) / d);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Can not divide by zero" << endl;
    }
}

bool Matrix::isSquare () const
{
    if (this->getRows() == this->getCols())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int Matrix::getRows() const
{
    return this->array.at(0).size();
}

int Matrix::getCols() const
{
    return this->array.size();
}

double Matrix::get(int row, int col) const
{
    if ((row < this->getRows()) && (col < this->getCols()))
    {
        return array[row][col];
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Couldn't get (" << row << "," << col <<"), element is out of bounds. dim = " << this->getRows() << " x " << this->getCols() << endl;
        return -1;
    }
}

int Matrix::getRow (int row, Matrix& dest) const
{
    if (!dest.isRow())
    {
        cout << "Destination matrix is not a row matrix" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->getCols(); i++)
        {
            dest.set(0, i, this->get(row,i));
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

int Matrix::addRows (int row, const Matrix& rrm)
{
    if (!rrm.isRow())
    {
        cout << "Specified matrix is not a row matrix." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else if (rrm.getCols() != this->getCols())
    {
        cout << "Matrix dimensions do not match." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else if (row >= this->getRows())
    {
        cout << "Given row number exceeds amount of rows in matrix." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rrm.getCols(); i++)
        {
            this->set(row, i, this->get(row, i) + rrm.get(0,i));
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

EDIT 6: I ran my code through VS's debugger, this is giving me an out of range exception at `Matrix::set (int row, int col, double value)`. The strange thing is, I've updated the method to do a range check. The call stack looks like this:

Matrix.cpp::set(int row, int col, double value) @ line 415 (`array.at(row).at(col) = value;`)

Matrix.cpp::Matrix(int r, int c) @ line 25 (closing parenthese of inner for loop)

Matrix.cpp::LUDecompose(Matrix& refLower, Matrix& refUpper) @ line 526 (`Matrix rowMatrix(1, this->getCols());`)

Test.cpp::Main @ line 35 (`cout << "Test.cpp regained control" << endl;`)

This is what the method currently looks like:

```
void Matrix::set(int row, int col, double value)
{
    if ((row < this->getRows()) && (col < this->getCols()))
    {
        array.at(row).at(col) = value;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Trying to assign to (" << row << "," << col << "): Out of bounds, dim = " << this->getRows() << " x " << this->getCols() << endl;
    }

}
```

EDIT 7:
After a bit of fiddling around in VS I was able to fix the code. I made multiple edits but I'm pretty sure the one that caused the above exception was in the fact that array.at(n) returns the n-th COLUMN (and not the n-th row, as can be seen in my code) and array.at(n).at(m) returns the elements at location (m,n) (where m is the m-th row and n is the n-th column)
Thanks to everyone for helping me out, here is a copy of the fixed set method:

```
void Matrix::set(int row, int col, double value)
{
    if ((row < this->getRows()) && (col < this->getCols()))
    {
        array.at(col).at(row) = value;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Trying to assign to (" << row << "," << col << "): Out of bounds, dim = " << this->getRows() << " x " << this->getCols() << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: TL;DR. You need to debug your programm.

Comment: Be sure to compile with debugging symbols (`-g` flag to `g++`) and try `bt` in GDB to see where your code crashes. This will also be a bit easier than printing to the console throughout your code for debugging.

Comment: Why does your `Matrix` class have an assignment operator (`operator=`)?   There is no need for it, since your Matrix class doesn't use pointers or any resources it needs to manage.  Get rid of it.  The compiler's default version is perfectly fine and works.  Your version -- we don't know what it does, whether it works, is buggy, etc.  You need to show your implementation, and then it can be determined if this is a cause for such issues.  If it is an issue -- again -- remove it.

Comment: I removed my = operator but this unfortunately didn't solve my problem. Thanks for helping me anyway. I didn't even know g++ generates default operators... So, If I understand you correctly, the only times when you need to overload these operators is when you have to manually manage resources (new, delete, malloc(), free(), pointers, ...)

Comment: Every C++ class has by default a copy constructor and assignment operator.  It isn't `g++`, those are the rules of the C++ language.  As to your question, yes, if you were to introduce pointers and dynamic memory management, you should have a user-defined version of these functions.

Comment: @shmoo6000 Also, I would suggest you temporarily change from using `[ ]` to access your vector elements with `at( )`.  The reason is that if you're going out of bounds, you will get an `out_of_range` exception thrown instead of a hard-to-diagnose segmentation fault error.

Comment: You should post `Matrix::set`, since you're calling it from `main`.  In addition, your constructor that takes a table -- you don't need to write a loop.  A vector is assignable. `Matrix::Matrix(Table t) : array(t) {}`

Comment: This is what's missing: `operator*=`, `/=`, `isSquare`, `getRows`, `getCols`, `get`, `getRow`, `addRows`.  As the first comment suggested, you need to debug your program using a debugger if you can't provide these functions.  The `set` functions did not cause any issues, and the LUDecompose is untestable due to the missing functions.

Comment: @shmoo6000 Well, `at()` to the rescue once again.  I know it's a pain to type in `at(x)` instead of `[x]`, but I've seen too many questions lately where a vector is used with no pointer usage, and the program has a seg fault or crashes.  This almost always means that there is an off-index issue.  When `at()` is temporarily used (you can switch back to `[ ]`), the error is easily diagnosed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When debugging a debug version of the program, there are additional run-time checks inserted into the code by compiler, invisible to you. These checks can detect if you are freeing memory twice, using uninitialized variables, overrunning allocated memory block, etc.. This is devised to help you if your program is doing something illegal which can go undetected. These checks do not exist in release versions so the errors/warnings will never be displayed, but your program will randomly crash and/or behave strangely.

In this case you have this warning:

*warning: Heap block at 00801188 modified at 00801198 past requested size of 8*

Run-time check has detected that you allocated 8 bytes at memory location 00801188 and that you wrote more than 8 bytes starting at this location, all the way to 00801198.

This **almost always** points to a problem when using array in a loop. Here is an example:

Suppose you allocate array of 10 integers: `int my[10];`
Now you want to write some values into every array member:

```
for ( int i=0; i<=10; i++ ) {
  my[i]=some_calculation();
}
```

This will cause **exact error like yours**. Since condition is `i<=10` (programmer was not careful, it should have been `i<10` or `i<=9`), last member written to is `my[10]`, the 11th array member, **but you allocated space only for 10**. So some other memory which is located right after your 10th member is overwritten causing unpredictable behavior in the program.

---

*To conclude, check all the loops where you are writing values to array members and make sure you are not writing to more array elements than you allocated.*

Answer (score 0):

one of the reason of program crashes is that you might be deleting some thing twice check your program for that or compile your program in IDE

Comment: Is there any IDE you'd recomend or will any of the commonly used C++ IDE's do?

Comment: use visual studio latest version